# LWJGL : Cannot create window using glfwCreateWindow

Tags: java, window, lwjgl, glfw

I'm new to game making and LWJGL, and I want to create a basic window. Here is my code :

```
if (!glfwInit()) {
    System.out.println("Failed to initialize GLFW");

    System.exit(1);

}

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);

window = glfwCreateWindow(this.SCREEN_WIDTH, this.SCREEN_HEIGHT,
        "Hello World", MemoryUtil.NULL, MemoryUtil.NULL);

if (window == MemoryUtil.NULL) {
    System.out.println("Failed to create window");

    System.exit(1);
}

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
GL.createCapabilities();
glfwSwapInterval(1);
```

But when I execute the code, I keep getting:

```
Failed to create window

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm following this tutorial on GitHub:

https://github.com/sriharshachilakapati/LWJGL-Tutorial-Series/blob/master/src/com/shc/tutorials/lwjgl/Game.java

Can someone show me what caused this to happen. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. After reading some articles on the web, it appears that downgrading Java was a solution that worked for a considerable number of people. So I tried installing Java Update 51 and everything is running smoothly now.